# How to sort in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

In the code below, I get the 9 latest objects in the table. Of this 9 objects, the last is presented as the latest. I wonder if it's possible to get the oppesite. Of this 9 objects, that the latest is the first in the result!? I hope my question isn't unclear!? It's hard to explain!

```
$query2 = "SELECT * from buildingObjects WHERE id > (SELECT MAX(id) - 9 FROM arkitekturobjekt)";
$result = $mysqli->query($query2);
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
// Show the objects here
}
```

Comment: The query given does not *quite* do what you describe.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Hmmm, but what does is do?

Comment: It returns any records that have an ID within the last 9 used. There is no guarantee that there are any records with the IDs in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only interested in the last 9 IDs, listed last to first, you could simply do:

```
SELECT * FROM buildingObjects ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9
```

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is  an **auto_increment primary key** index you can go for `ORDER BY id DESC`, still if you are also storing dates or date and time, you could go for the `date`  field order instead.